# How to correctly join tables in Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, maven, spring-boot

I have a User, and the user has Expenses. In expenses table I want to have the expense id, the user who made the expense and the amount of expense. In the user table I want user id, his username, his current balance and list of all expenses he's made.

I want to join those 2, but I don't know how to correctly reference user, therefore user form Expense class is always null.

First, I send post request to create a user:

```
{
    "username":"abcd",
    "balance":"100"
}
```

then I want to create an expense, but here I'm not sure how to correctly send a User:

```
{
    "username":"abcd",
    "id":"1",
    "balance":"100",
    "amount":"20"
}
```

and this doesn't work, then I tried like this:

```
{
    "User":{
    "username":"abcd",
    "id":"1",
    "balance":"100"
    },
    "amount":"20"
}
```

and that didn't work either.

This is the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
    private String username;
    private Double balance = 0.0;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Expense> expenses;
    ...
```

I removed getters and setters from here.

Here is the Expense class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Expenses")
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    private Double amount;
    ...
```

For saving the expense I use `.save()` from `JpaRepository<Expense, Long>` and for retrieveing everyting I use `.findAll()`.

The result is always the same: get for all expenses gives

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "user": null,
        "amount": 20
}
```

and get for all users gives

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "username": "abcd",
        "balance": 100,
        "expenses": []
}
```

Now I'm not sure whether I'm sending the requests the wrong way or joining the tables the wrong way or both.

EDIT: here is `ExpenseController`:

```
@RestController
public class ExpenseController {

    @Autowired
    IExpenseService expenseService;

    @GetMapping("/expenses")
    public List<Expense> findExpenses() {
        return expenseService.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/expenses")
    public void createNewExpense(@RequestBody Expense expense) {
        expenseService.createNewExpense(expense);
    }
}
```

`createNewUser(...)` from `ExpenseService`

```
@Override
    public void createNewExpense(Expense expense) {
        repository.save(expense);
    }
```

and `ExpenseRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {
}
```

`UserController`:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> findUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User findUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        if (userService.checkIfUsernameIsTaken(user)) {

            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("status", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            response.put("errors", "Username is already taken");
            response.put("timestamp", new Date());

            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            userService.createNewUser(user);
            User currentUser = userService.findById(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()));
            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("id", currentUser.getId());
            response.put("username", currentUser.getUsername());
            response.put("balance", currentUser.getBalance());
            response.put("expenses", currentUser.getExpenses());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/users/{id}/{balance}")
    public void updateBalance(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Double balance) {
        userService.updateBalance(id, balance);
    }
}
```

the rest of the User model is the same as the Expense model.

Comment: show the method that gets the User/Expense object and saves everything. Just to be more clear here

Comment: You're mixing two things that should be unrelated: 1. your persistence model (JPA entities), 2. your HTTP API inputs. Use different classes to model those two parts. And think about what your API should accept in order to create an expense: you need an amount, and something which uniquely identifies a user. So the JSON object should contain an amount, and a userId. Create a DTO class that maps to this JSON structure. Then use JPA to get the user identified by the received user ID, and create an expense containing the received amount, and the found user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send post request with this payload (field 'user' begins with a small letter), and i think the 'id' field in user object should be enough

```
  { 
   "user":{
     "username":"abcd",
     "id":"1",
     "balance":"100"
    },
    "amount":"20"
  }
```

EDIT: Also you need to add @JsonIgnoreProperties("expenses") to your Expense entity to prevent jackson from recursive reading json

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Expenses")
public class Expense {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties("expenses")
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  private Double amount;
.....
```

Comment: hell breaks loose when I try it with 'user'. I get ```Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)```